# post_row_actions not working for hierarchical post type

Tags: custom-post-types, hierarchical, row-actions

I'm working on a plugin where I have a Custom Post Type (CPT) registered and I need to add custom row actions to *that* particular post type. But could not make the following code hooked to [`post_row_actions`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_row_actions/) work:

```
function ttest_copy_button( $actions, $post )
{
    // var_dump($actions);
    if( 'ttest' === $post->post_type ) {
        // pass nonce to check and verify false request
        $nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'copy_content' );

        // add our button
        $actions['copy_content'] = '<a data-nonce="'. $nonce .'" href="javascript:" role="button">'. esc_html__( 'Copy Content', 'ttest' ) .'</a>';
    }

    return $actions;
}

add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'ttest_copy_button', 10, 2 );
```

My CPT code is:

```
function ttest_register_cpt() {
    register_post_type( 'ttest', array(
        'labels'              => array(
            'menu_name' => __('TTest', 'ttest')
        ),
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'description'         => __( 'Get the test information', 'ttest' ),
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies'          => array(),
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-book-alt',
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'menu_position'       => 6,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'ttest' ),
        'capability_type'     => 'post'
    ) );
}

add_action( 'init', 'ttest_register_cpt', 5 );
```

When the `var_dump($actions);` line is active I see the code dump in all the other default post types, even on the WooCommerce `product` post type, but **not** in my custom post type.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be wrong while saying:

> I see the code dump in *all* the other default post types

Because your dump won't show code dump on the default post type `page`, and here is where the clue lies - `page` is `hierarchical`.

If you see the documentation of `post_row_actions`, you can see the description saying:

> The filter is evaluated only for ***non-hierarchical*** post types.

### Meet with the `page_row_actions`

As your post type is hierarchical you have to use [`page_row_actions`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/page_row_actions/) the counterpart for the hierarchical post types.